# How to direct DLT target table to a Unity Catalog Metastore

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-live-tables, databricks-unity-catalog

This question is pretty straightforward. Seems like in DLT, you can define the output table name like below:

```
@dlt.table(name="my_table_name")
def my_pipeline():
  ...
```

This writes to the hive_metastore catalog, but how do I customize it for a different catalog?

Answer (score 4):

As of right now (august 2022), DLT doesn't support Unity Catalog yet. It should be available in the near future.

Update June 2023rd: DLT [started to support Unity Catalog since April 2023rd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/delta-live-tables/2023/16/).

P.S. You can join [Databricks quarterly roadmap webinar](https://www.databricks.com/p/webinar/databricks-q3-product-roadmap-webinar) if you want to get latest updates about newer features

Comment: Is this still the case or do we have now UNITY catalog available with DLT?

Comment: If it’s not announced then not yet

Comment: @AlexOtt are you aware if it's on the roadmap and what the ETA is? Feels weird that these core Databricks features don't work with each other. I love UC and DLT, but by adopting UC it makes DLT useless, forcing users into other workflow frameworks

Comment: I can’t give exact ETA, but I think that it was covered by the quarterly roadmap webinar…