# How to publish delta live table(DLT) in different catalog instead of hive_metastore

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, databricks, delta-live-tables

**Hi, community,** 
  I want to publish(save) the delta live table(DLT) into a different catalog database.
  The following image target field only asks for the database name, not for the catalog.
[image]

I've referred to documentation but couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to direct DLT target table to a Unity Catalog Metastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73339731/how-to-direct-dlt-target-table-to-a-unity-catalog-metastore)

Answer (score 4):

Unity Catalog isn't supported in Delta Live Tables yet - as I remember, it's planned to be released really soon.

Right now, there is a workaround - you can push data into a location on S3 that then could be added as a table in [Unity Catalog external location](https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/unity-catalog/manage-external-locations-and-credentials.html).

P.S. It's not recommended to use default "Storage location" - it won't work with Unity Catalog as it's on [DBFS Root](https://docs.databricks.com/dbfs/index.html#dbfs-root). It's better to push it to a S3.

Comment: Are you able to create persistent views on external tables to unity catalog? I know you aren't able to from the hive_metastore

Comment: you should be able - I don't remember such limitation, but I don't remember out of the head

Comment: also how do you then import the external dlt tables to UC? and will automatically grab the updates

Comment: The same way as other tables - create table … location …, just in UC external location

Comment: I see, unfortunately I don't think it will work well for our use case because it only reads the table once... so after each update we will have to reread the table

Comment: You need to check - content will be always updated

Comment: This suggests otherwise, no? https://docs.databricks.com/data-governance/unity-catalog/create-tables.html#insert-records-from-a-path-into-an-existing-table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250094/discussion-between-marc-and-alex-ott).

Comment: `COPY INTO` is used for inserting completely new data. Data written into table from "outside" are automatically visible even with the Hive Metastore - that is one of the pain points that Delta format solves compared to Parquet